# Mongoose - How do I use the countDocuments options specifically limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/ it seems that it is possible to pass in options.
One of those options is limit, which is what I am interested in right now.

When I look at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments it does not seem like it is possible to pass in any options.

How do I pass in the limit option for countDocuments?

Comment: Why would you pass in a limit to countdocuments? If you want to count all documents in a large collection, use the `estimatedDocumentCount()` function.

Comment: So with countDocuments we are actually passing in a query. In most cases it will hit an index, in a few others it might not.
The limit option as I understand it from Mongodb:
"The maximum number of documents to count."

Since the number of documents that match the query is sometimes quite large, and this slows down the count we believe.
If we pass in some limit like 5000 or even 250 it can stop counting when it reaches that, and might return quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems possible to do this.
See:

```
  let mongooseQuery = model.find();
  mongooseQuery.setOptions({limit: 5});
  mongooseQuery.countDocuments(query, function countResults(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      //handle error
    }
    console.log(result);
  });
```

I guess I was looking to pass in the parameters directly to the countDocuments the way it works from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a good question and you can do that with aggregation:

```
    const limit = 100;
    const result = await db.collection('YourCollection').aggregate([
        { $limit: limit },
        { $count: "count"}
    ]).toArray();
```

For more options of [db.collection.aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)